# How to forward external traffic to external ip

Tags: redirect, networking, iptables, portforwarding, forwarding

I have messages coming to public IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:23456 and i wish to forward this to public IP YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:65432. i cannot find a way to do this through my Netgear N300, so i am looking at other options. one potential solution would be to portforward the packets being sent to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:23456 to the internal IP ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ:65432 and then use either a mechanism on windows or iptables on linux to preform the forward on to public IP YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:65432.

However my knowledge of networking is not sufficient to how how to setup the config in iptables, to know of software to preform this in windows, or if there  should be something in the router i am unaware of that is capable of this. Please advise.

Comment: netsh portproxy perhaps https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731068(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the destination address, so you'll need destination NAT (DNAT). Changing the port address as well requires PAT.

Both are not likely supported by a consumer router, but many business-grade routers can do this.

Comment: as specified i have a  netgear N300 (consumer router), so this is not a feasible solution for me.  i need to forward the traffic from a server internally back out to its new address.